# By default, does TensorFlow use GPU/CPU simultaneously for computing or GPU only?

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, deep-learning, gpu

By default, TensorFlow will use our available GPU devices. That said, does TensorFlow use GPUs **and CPUs** simultaneously for **computing**, or GPUs for computing and CPUs for job handling (no matter how, CPUs are always active, as I think)?

Comment: It depends on many factors. But if your pipeline is correct the data augmentation is in CPU while the GPUs are computing the batch. You can monitor it with htop, nvidia-smi and check memory throughput as well - a bottleneck can be found easily.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

But from what I'm aware TensorFlow only uses either GPU or CPU depending on what installation you ran. For example if you used `pip install TensorFlow` for python 2 or `python3 -m pip install TensorFlow` for python 3 you'll **only** use the CPU version.

Vise versa for GPU.

If you still have any questions or if this did not correctly answer your question feel free to ask me more.

Comment: You're wrong - GPU version supports also CPU. Check the official documentations, it states: "If a TensorFlow operation has both CPU and GPU implementations, by default the GPU devices will be given priority when the operation is assigned to a device."  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu

Answer (score 4):

Generally it uses both, the CPU and the GPU (assuming you are using a GPU-enabled TensorFlow). What actually gets used depends on the actual operations that your code is using.

For each operation available in TensorFlow, there are several "implementations" of such operation, generally a CPU implementation and a GPU one. Some operations only have CPU implementations as it makes no sense for a GPU implementation, but overall most operations are available for both devices.

If you make custom operations then you need to provide implementations that you want.

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow operations come packaged with a list of devices they can execute on and a list of associated priorities.

For example, a convolution is very conducive to computation on a GPU; but can still be done on a CPU whereas scalar additions should definitely be done on a CPU. You can override this selection using tf.Device and the key attached to the device of interest.